# Is there any option in mysql to set one column should not bigger than another column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Is there any option in mysql to set one column should not bigger than another column

In this case both columns are type integer.

Comment: Try specifying a check constraint. Or try adding insert/update triggers if that works.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) , then we know better what you are talking about or trying to get..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean: *for each row*, one column *value* should not be bigger than another column *value*.

Starting MySQL 8.0(.16), this can be implemented with a check constraint:

```
create table mytable (
    id int,
    big_col int,
    small_col int,
    check (small_col <= big_col)
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e1bd2161dce19e442ee03749f4cd299b)**

```
insert into mytable(id, big_col, small_col) values(1, 1, 1);
-- allowed

insert into mytable(id, big_col, small_col) values(2, 1, 2);
-- error: Check constraint 'mytable_chk_1' is violated.
```

---

In earlier versions of MySQL, a typical solution is to use triggers for insert and update:

```
delimiter //
create trigger mytrigger_insert 
before insert on mytable for each row
begin
    if new.big_col < new.small_col then
        signal sqlstate '45000' 
            set message_text = 'small_col must not be bigger than big_col';
    end if;
end
//
delimiter ;

delimiter //
create trigger mytrigger_update 
before update on mytable for each row
begin
    if new.big_col < new.small_col then
        signal sqlstate '45000' 
            set message_text = 'small_col must not be bigger than big_col';
    end if;
end
//
delimiter ;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iDRFFfZewS7metRNH1B6rP/0)**:

```
insert into mytable(id, big_col, small_col) values(1, 1, 0);
-- ok

insert into mytable(id, big_col, small_col) values(2, 1, 2);
-- error: ER_SIGNAL_EXCEPTION: small_col must not be bigger than big_col

update mytable set small_col = 2 where id = 1;
-- error: ER_SIGNAL_EXCEPTION: small_col must not be bigger than big_col
```

Comment: No, correction `CHECK` is MySQL  8.0.16+,only see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) .. Well i was close enough :-)

Comment: *"In earlier versions of MySQL, a typical solution is to use triggers for insert and update:"* To add to the answer in the oldest MySQL versions which supports triggers you would need to use a workaround like `UPDATE 'small_col must not be bigger than big_col'`instead to trigger a "good" [error message](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iDRFFfZewS7metRNH1B6rP/0) as `signal sqlstate` is not supported there In general anything which can make a syntax error could/should work like a [dot (.)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iDRFFfZewS7metRNH1B6rP/1) to get a "good" readable error message..

Comment: @RaymondNijland:  I think that the `signal` statement has been around since version 5.5... Your comment about oldest versions relate to pre-5.5 versions?

Comment: *"Your comment about oldest versions relate to pre-5.5 versions? "* Yes that is what i meant, indeed `SIGNAL` is a MySQL 5.5+ [valid](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) statement, the older pre MySQL 5.5 [versions](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.4/en/conditions-and-handlers.html) do not have that `signal` statement.. Do the remember that old MySQL website/manual design ?  Anyhow i think i will remove mine comment as it it unlikely poeple are still running MySQL 5.0 to MySQL 5.4 nowadways...

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF(exp1, exp2, exp3)` to set number, the exp2 can change to what you want it is.

This will update the column1 not beyond column2.

```sql
UPDATE table
SET column1 = IF(100 > column2, column2, 100)
where ...
```

Laravel query

```php
\DB::select("update table 
set column1 = IF(:num1 > column2, column2, :num2)  
where ...", ["num1" => 100, "num2" => 100])
```

Hope this can help you or others.

Comment: That Laravel code `\DB::raw("IF($int > column2, column2, $int)")` part feels very very SQL injection prone..  Not sure didn't do Laravel programming for a while besides that it might be fine if it used like that with the `update()`function.. ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry for that. I have updated my answer.